# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() when iterating through masked array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to iterate through a masked array that contains many NaNs:

```
[[[-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
  ...
  [-- 0.0 0.0 ... -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]]

 [[-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
  ...
  [-- 0.0 0.0 ... -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]]

 [[-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
  ...
  [-- 0.0 0.0 ... -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]]
```

I have created a function to iterate through this masked array using a `for` loop which catches items with 1=<value<2, 2=<value<4, 4=<value<8, 8<8.

```
# Define function to count the occurences of different DHW thresholds being crossed
def threshold_count (enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data):
    
    # Create for loop to examine all data
    for i in range(0,len(enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data)):
        
        # Define different threshold counts
        enso_event_dhw_1_count = 0
        enso_event_dhw_2_count = 0
        enso_event_dhw_4_count = 0
        enso_event_dhw_8_count = 0
    
        # Define if statements to segment different threshold counts
        if (1 <= enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data[i] < 2):
            enso_event_dhw_1_count = enso_event_dhw_1_count + 1
    
        if (2 <= enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data[i] < 4):
            enso_event_dhw_2_count = enso_event_dhw_2_count + 1
        
        if (8 <= enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data[i] < 8):
            enso_event_dhw_4_count = enso_event_dhw_4_count + 1
        
        if (8 <= enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data[i]):
            enso_event_dhw_8_count = enso_event_dhw_8_count + 1
    
    return enso_event_dhw_1_count, enso_event_dhw_2_count, enso_event_dhw_4_count, enso_event_dhw_8_count`
```

However, when using this function I get

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

How may I be able to overcome this?

Comment: Are you really using Python 2.7, or did you just use this tag accidentally?

Answer (score 1):

> a masked array that contains many Nans

You are mistaken - the array you show contains arrays of arrays rather than numbers or NaNs. A naive correction is to call the function with flattened data, e. g. if the variable `z` holds your data:

```
… threshold_count(np.ravel(z))
```

- then the function works after of course the initializations of the different threshold counts are moved outside the loop.

But a loop is not making good use of NumPy. Better should be this implementation:

```
def threshold_count(enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data):
    enso_event_dhw_1_count = np.sum((1 <= enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data) & (enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data < 2))
    enso_event_dhw_2_count = np.sum((2 <= enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data) & (enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data < 4))
    enso_event_dhw_4_count = np.sum((4 <= enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data) & (enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data < 8))
    enso_event_dhw_8_count = np.sum( 8 <= enso_events_dhw_thresholds_data )
    return enso_event_dhw_1_count, enso_event_dhw_2_count, enso_event_dhw_4_count, enso_event_dhw_8_count
```

Even better than that is using e. g. [`numpy.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), which makes the task so simple that defining a function is no longer useful:

```
… np.histogram(z, (1, 2, 4, 8, np.inf))
```